# Laptop doesn't make it past the windows logo

Tags: windows-10, boot, laptop

I'm running Windows 10 (and have been since it was available). This morning when I went to turn my laptop on it didn't progress past the spinning dots and logo. After a few tries I got it to try startup repair, but that left me at a black screen and only my cursor was there. I had an unexpected shutdown last night, and I'm fairly sure that's the cause. What should I try?

Comment: You have critical system files corrupt.  I experienced the same thing, ended up being, my hdd has 300 reallocated sectors on it.

Comment: @Ramhound, wouldn't surprise me if what I think happened did happen. What did you end up doing? Did you manage to save your files?

Comment: I was able to salvage some of my files.

Answer (score -1):

Boot your PC in safe mode with command prompt and run the following command:

```
sfc /scannow
```

This will fix any corrupted files.

To enter safe mode:

- Press <kbd>F8</kbd> when the boot menu appears.
- Use the arrow keys to highlight the appropriate safe mode option, and then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.